# Cannot open URL. Please check this URL is correct: http://localhost:8080/

Tags: intellij-idea, error-handling

I am using **IntelliJ Ideea 13.1.4** and I encountered this error - after I Run / Debug my project, after "`Artifact portal-webapp:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully`"

I get this error but it has been working util now...

Do you Have any idea what should it be?

[image]

Comment: Did you change the port? Is some other application running on port 8080? What if you open that URL in a browser?

Comment: It seems that web server is stopped. Let check the server process , apache etc, is running or not.

Comment: I tried to change the port but still that error. The browser is teling me "this webpage has a redirect loop" and tries to go on "http://localhost:8080/portal-webapp/auth/login" but... nothing

Comment: with another project, same tomcat, same port/JMX works without problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on production profile but I don't know how I was building until now automatic on dev profile. Now I put a -Pdev to the mvn clean install command I had in a .bat file and all is ok.

Comment: I face with same problem. I read your answer but not clearly. Please improve your answer.

Comment: mvn clean install -Pdev - it was the profile for production.

Answer (score 4):

It appears Idea is trying to wait for your page to return 200 response and then open the external web browser. If this does not happen (e.g. your application returns a redirect due to authentication filters), Idea is just spamming your application with requests and then complains about not being able to open the web page.

Comment: this is what happened to me. Thank you very much for the explanation :)